# Load a dynamic custom user control added during page execution (button click event)

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I'm trying to add a custom control to a panel (containing a "form" to input data) during a button click event and I want to access it's methods like .Validate() after this data has been inputted. But when I try to do so the ctrl comes with null value.

Here's part of my code :

```
protected void btnNext2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ...
ctrlCompliance = (Compliance)LoadControl("../../ascx/SRM/Compliance.ascx");
ctrlCompliance.ReadOnly = false;
pnlCompliance.Controls.Add(ctrlCompliance);
...
}

protected void btnNext3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ...
ctrlCompliance = pnlCompliance.Controls[0] as Compliance;
ctrlCompliance.Validate() <- this is allways null
...
}
```

I cannot use Page_Init as most of the solutions propose and really need to load it only during that button click. Did someone had the same problem as me?

Answer (score 0):

You should load it anyway using Page_Init, but set its visible property to False. Then using javascript or code-behind you can change its visible property to True when you need to show the print button.

So move:

```
ctrlCompliance = (Compliance)LoadControl("../../ascx/SRM/Compliance.ascx");
ctrlCompliance.ReadOnly = false;
pnlCompliance.Controls.Add(ctrlCompliance);
```

to Page_Init

Comment: I can't. I need the control to register a JS function only after btnNext2 click.

Comment: I still dont understand why you dont load the button on Page_Init?

Comment: Cause the page is divided by tabs. And I only want to load the control on the second tab!

Comment: What kind of tabs are they? Bootstrap/JQuerey?

Comment: Jquery. My problem is that I have subtabs which register an document.ready event that is not loaded when registered at the first page_load.